# setting a date field in sharepoint 2013 with workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am trying to set a date field in my SharePoint list and the logic for it is if the status changes then the date that the it is changed goes in my date column. I am building my workflow in SharePoint designer. I did a if statement then set date to current date. For some reason it wont print out the date in the column. I have also tried creating a variable but it still wont print it in the column.

[image]

Help Please it is driving my crazy!!

Comment: You should add a "Log to history" action before or after your Set action and check the history list after testing, to be sure that your if condition works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are different return types, make sure you are using Long date or Short Date if the column is single line of text. If you are setting a Date/Time column, make sure you return it as ISO Format. Otherwise which variable are you using to set it? You could use the "Modified" column, or go into the Workflow Context and put Workflow Last Updated.